# How to disable particular date in glDatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I checked in the documentation but I think there are no options for disabling a particular date.

This is the [documentation](http://glad.github.io/glDatePicker/#examples) I am referring.

This the code.

```
    var today = new Date();
    var future = new Date(today);

    future.setDate(today.getDate() + 60);

    Meeting.$dateInput.glDatePicker({
        showAlways: true,
        hideOnClick: false,
        allowYearSelect: false,
        selectableDateRange: [ {
            from: today,
            to: future
        }]
    });
```

Calender works fine but I want to disable some dates. Something like passing an array of disable dates.

Comment: please share what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The way to disable particular date is make the other dates selectable.

Check example 2 from the url: http://glad.github.io/glDatePicker/#examples

```
$('#example2').glDatePicker(
{
    showAlways: true,
    allowMonthSelect: false,
    allowYearSelect: false,
    prevArrow: '',
    nextArrow: '',
    selectedDate: new Date(2013, 8, 5),
    selectableDateRange: [
        { from: new Date(2013, 8, 1),
            to: new Date(2013, 8, 10) },
        { from: new Date(2013, 8, 19),
            to: new Date(2013, 8, 22) },
    ],
    selectableDates: [
        { date: new Date(2013, 8, 24) },
        { date: new Date(2013, 8, 30) }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! But its does not seems good to calulate and pass so many dates for disabling the date.

Comment: The date picker you are using doesn't have the option to disable the dates. So we can either do the calculation or look for other datepicker.